# R - problem with foreach %dopar% inside function called by optim

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Calling a function that includes foreach %dopar% construct from optim causes an error:

```
> workers <- startWorkers(6) # 6 cores
> 
> registerDoSMP(workers)
> 
> t0 <- Sys.time() 
>
> optim(w,maxProb2,control=list(fnscale=-1))
> 
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "unused argument(s) (isPrebuilt = TRUE)"
> 
> Sys.time()-t0
>
> Time difference of 2.032 secs
> 
> stopWorkers(workers)
```

The called function looks like that:

```
> maxProb2 <- function(wp) {
>   
>   r <- foreach (i=s0:s1, .combine=c) %dopar% { pf(i,x[i,5],wp,isPrebuilt=TRUE) }
>   
>   cat("w=",wp,"max=",sum(r),"\n")
>   
>   sum(r)
>   
> }
```

pf is some other function, x is a static table of pre-computed elements.

Also calling the function to be optimized just once causes the same error:

```
> workers <- startWorkers(6) # 6 cores
>
> Warning message:
> In startWorkers(6) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP1
>
> registerDoSMP(workers)
>
> maxProb2(w)
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "unused argument(s) (isPrebuilt = TRUE)"
>
> stopWorkers(workers)
```

What's strange, the identical code works fine when called directly a single time (optim calles the same function many times):

```
> workers <- startWorkers(6) # 6 - ilosc rdzeni
> 
> Warning message:
> In startWorkers(6) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP1
>
> registerDoSMP(workers)
> 
> r <- foreach (i=s0:s1, .combine=c) %dopar% { pf(i,x[i,5],w,isPrebuilt=TRUE) } 
>   
> sum(r)
> [1] 187.1781
> 
> stopWorkers(workers)
```

The called function (maxProb2) works fine, when %do% is used instead of %dopar%.

**How can I correctly call a function including a foreach %dopar% construction?**

UPDATE 2011-07-17:

I have renamed the pf function into probf but the problem remains.

probf functions is defined in the script, not in some external package.

Two notes: OS: Windows 7, IDE: Revolution Analytics Enterprise 4.3

```
> workers <- startWorkers(workerCount = 3)
>
> registerDoSMP(workers)
>
> maxProb2(w)
>
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "probf""
```

Comment: Please always include the exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 24):

I ran into the same problem an the issue is with the environment not being included in the sub-threads. Your error

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "simple_fn""

can be reproduced by this very simple example:

```
simple_fn <- function(x)
    x+1

test_par <- function(){
    library("parallel")
    no_cores <- detectCores()
    library("foreach")
    cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
    library("doSNOW")
    registerDoSNOW(cl)
    out <- foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {
        simple_fn(i)
    }

    stopCluster(cl)
    return(out)
}

test_par()
```

Now all you need to to is to change the `foreach(i=1:10)` into `foreach(i=1:10, .export=c("simple_fn"))`. If you want to export your complete global environment then just write `.export=ls(envir=globalenv())` and you will have it for better or worse.

Comment: I've always wondered why `.export=ls()` is not the default. Seems like a good idea in most situations, judging from the number of posts on this topic... Any idea?

Comment: @Ruben - actually it makes sense as parallelizing is most relevant when working with large datasets

Comment: But then you'd load chunks of data individually in each node, right? I wouldn't load the whole df in the global session then. And some stuff is automatically loaded (e.g. the vectors you're iterating over). Moreover, using ls didn't work as I expected just now. The only solution where I reliably get what I predict to happen is to define inside the loop. Inefficient, sometimes ugly though.

Comment: @Ruben multidplyr has an example how you can go about loading subdatasets: https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.md I have often loaded the full dataset into the workers as I've tested different number of spline knots in each model that have required the entire dataset. This is still efficient since I often have some munging datasets in memory that I don't want to send allover the place...

Answer (score 2):

[[Edited]]

Your `pf` function and your "static table" `x` must be distributed to all worker nodes. You must read the documentation for your parallel library on how that works.

It seems to be that when run through optim, the `pf` function it finds is another one (probably `stats::pf`, which does not have an `isPrebuilt` argument).

Can you try renaming your `pf` function (for example to `mypf`)?

```
mypf <- pf # renaming the function

maxProb2 <- function(wp) {
  r <- foreach (i=s0:s1, .combine=c) %dopar% { mypf(i,x[i,5],wp,isPrebuilt=TRUE) }
  cat("w=",wp,"max=",sum(r),"\n")
  sum(r)
}
```

Or, if your `pf` function is part of a package with a namespace (say, `mypackage`), you could reference it like this: `mypackage::pf`

```
maxProb2 <- function(wp) {
  r <- foreach (i=s0:s1, .combine=c) %dopar% { mypackage::pf(i,x[i,5],wp,isPrebuilt=TRUE) }
  cat("w=",wp,"max=",sum(r),"\n")
  sum(r)
}
```

Comment: How shoudl I make sure that the function being called and the table are distributed to worker nodes?

Comment: `pf` exists in the built-in `stats` package and is the distribution function for the F distribution.

Comment: I updated the answer since it seems to be what I suspected - the wrong `pf` function is called.

Comment: I have renamed the pf function into probf but the problem remains.

probf functions is defined in the script, not in some external package.

Two notes: OS: Windows 7, IDE: Revolution Analytics Enterprise 4.3

> workers <- startWorkers(workerCount = 3)
> registerDoSMP(workers)
> maxProb2(w)
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "probf""

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for problem with foreach %dopar% is to reinstall these packages:

```
install.packages("doSNOW")

install.packages("doParallel") 

install.packages("doMPI")
```

As mentioned in various threads at StackOverflow, these are responsible for parallelism in R. Bug which existed in old versions of these packages is now removed. It worked in my case. I should mention that it will most likely help even though you are not using these packages in your project/package.