# Function not found in R doParallel 'foreach' - Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "raster""

Tags: r

I am trying to use a high performance cluster at my institution for the first time and I have hit a problem that I can't resolve.

The following code returns an error:

```
ptime<-system.time({
  r <- foreach(z = 1:length(files),.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
    raster <- raster(paste(folder,files[1],sep=""))
    data<-getValues(raster)
    clp <- na.omit(data)
    for(i in 1:length(classes)){
      results[i,z]<-length(clp[clp==classes[i]])/length(clp)
      print(z)
    }
  }
})

Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "raster""
```

A also tried a different foreach code for another task I have:

```
r <- foreach (i=1:length(poly)) %dopar% {
  clip<-gIntersection(paths,poly[i,])
  lgth<-gLength(clip)
  vid<-poly@data[i,3]
  path.lgth[i,] <- c(vid,lgth)
  print(i)
}
```

and this time the gIntersection function isn't found. Obviously the packages are all installed and loaded. After reading some forum posts it seem it has to do with the environment that the functions execute/operate in.

Can someone please help? I'm not a programmer!

Thank you!

Update:

I have adjusted my code for the solution provided:

```
results<-matrix(nrow=length(classes),ncol=length(files))
dimnames(results)[[1]]<-classes
dimnames(results)[[2]]<-files

ptime<-system.time({
    foreach(z = 1:length(files),.packages="raster") %dopar% {
    raster <- raster(paste(folder,files[z],sep=""))
    data<-getValues(raster)
    clp <- na.omit(data)
    for(i in 1:length(classes)){
      results[i,z]<-length(clp[clp==classes[i]])/length(clp)
      print(z)
    }
  }
})
```

But what I get is an output (my results matrix) filled with na's. As you can see I create a matrix object called results to fill with results (which works with for loops), but after reading the documentation for foreach it seems that you save your results differently with this function.

And advice on what I should choose for the .combine argument?

Comment: Try using the `.packages` parameter of `foreach`. The packages are not loaded on the workers.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf Page 8 and 9. Or `?foreach`. That's where the information given in Roland's comment can be found.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This problem is solved but now I have a new problem. I will edit my original question.

Comment: Please refrain from changing your question to ask a new one. This will confuse future visitors. If you have a new problem, ask a new question. And this is clearly a new problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for an idea on how the site works

Comment: I was just trying to build on the knowledge base that the previous responders already had regarding my code.

Comment: [cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf](cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) is a broken link. The new one is [cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html](cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In the [vignette of foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html) and the help page of foreach, the argument `.packages` is pointed out as necessary to provide when using parallel computation with functions that are not loaded by default. So your code in the first example should be:

```
ptime<-system.time({
  r <- foreach(z = 1:length(files),
               .combine=cbind, 
               .packages='raster') %dopar% {
      # some code
      # and more code
  }
})
```

---

**Some more explanation**

The `foreach` package does a lot of setting up behind the scenes. What happens is the following (in principle, technical details are a tad more complicated):

- `foreach` sets up a system of "workers" that you can see as separate R sessions that are each committed to a different core in a cluster.
- The function that needs to be carried out is loaded into each "worker" session, together with the objects needed to carry out the function
- each worker calculates the result for a subset of the data
- The results of the calculation on the different workers is put together and reported in the "master" R session.

As the workers can be seen as separate R sessions, packages from the "master" session are not automatically loaded. You have to specify which packages should be loaded in those worker sessions, and that's what the `.package` argument of `foreach` is used for.

---

Note that when you use other packages (e.g. `parallel` or `snowfall`), you'll have to set up these workers explicitly, and also take care of passing objects and loading packages on the worker sessions.

Comment: Also all dependencies must be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I dealt with the same problem. My solution is

1. Prepare your function in a separate R file.

**Function.R**

```
f <- function(parameters...){Body...}
```

2. Source your Function within foreach loop

**MainFile.R**

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-2) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, .libPaths("C:/R/win-library/4.0")) #Give your R library path
output <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
source("~/Function.R") # That is the main point. Source your Function File here.
temp <- f(parameters...) # use your custom function after sourcing 
temp
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the "*could not find function*" error using `foreach` too. Often this question relates to a function from a package not being available to the `foreach` workers. However my use case is when non-package/custom/orphaned(?)/unexported(?) functions defined in the same script as `foreach`. Instead of creating a new package and exporting the functions this is a dirty quick fix. Here's the scenario:

A single script with:

```
funA(){
    ...
}

funB(){
    ...
}

funC(){     
    foreach(){
        funA(); funB()
    }
}

funC()
```

two functions `funA` & `funB` defined before `funC` and then `funC` called. Looks like these first two aren't considered in the global environment of `funC` even though they are in the same script, hence the error. Easy solution was to cut & paste `funA` & `funB` to the top of `funC`'s definition like so:

```
funC(){
    funA(){
        ...
    }
    funB(){
        ...
    }       
    foreach(){}
}

funC()
```

Comment: In this thread you can find an explanation what is going on in such a case and a clean solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638393/7684730