# Save results of foreach loop in a matrix

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to adapt a for loop to use it in parallel as a foreach loop. For the for loop I create an empty matrix then fill it with the values generated by the for loop. But this approach doesn't work in the foreach loop,

```
results<-matrix(nrow=length(classes),ncol=length(files))
dimnames(results)[[1]]<-classes
dimnames(results)[[2]]<-files

ptime<-system.time({
    foreach(z = 1:length(files),.packages="raster") %dopar% {
      raster <- raster(paste(folder,files[z],sep=""))
      data<-getValues(raster)
      clp <- na.omit(data)
      for(i in 1:length(classes)){
        results[i,z]<-length(clp[clp==classes[i]])/length(clp)
        print(z)
      }
    }
})
```

My results matrix is still just filled with na's, it doesn't get populated.

z is a raster file, i is a vector of numerical classes. I want the number of cells in raster z for each class i, and then divide this by the total number of cells in raster z to get this as a proportion.

Any advice on how I can save this as a matrix/dataframe in a foreach loop?

Thank you in advance.

---

*Follow up of this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704235/function-not-found-in-r-doparallel-foreach-error-in-task-1-failed-cou)*

Answer (score 4):

You haven't understood how `foreach` works. It isn't the same as a `for` loop. Please study the package vignettes. Here are two simple examples:

```
library(foreach)
#you need to assign the loop result
res <- foreach(z = 1:5, .combine=c) %do% {
  a <- z
  a #return value for the iterations
}

res
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5


res <- foreach(z = 1:5, .combine=cbind) %:% foreach(i = 10:13, .combine=c) %do% {
  a <- z+i
  a
}
res
#      result.1 result.2 result.3 result.4 result.5
# [1,]       11       12       13       14       15
# [2,]       12       13       14       15       16
# [3,]       13       14       15       16       17
# [4,]       14       15       16       17       18
```

Note that you should always test your loop without parallelization first. Also, it doesn't make sense to use `print` inside the loop. You won't see the printed values anyway when you run the loop in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have been reading the cran documentation but I can't relate what I'm doing to the examples given. I am trying my code on a single core at the moment, just trying to debug the code.