# R / foreach-package: how to pass customized function to clusters?

Tags: r, foreach

This post describes how to pass packages to all clusters:
[Function not found in R doParallel 'foreach' - Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "raster""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704235/function-not-found-in-r-doparallel-foreach-error-in-task-1-failed-cou)

However, I would like to pass functions to the clusters (because I use them in the foreach-loop), that are not part of an R-package. How can I do this?

Edit: 
My only idea was to run another foreach-loop from 1:#cluster before the actual foreach-loop and define the function in each cluster. But this is a) not very elegant and b) it doesn't work (function can still not be found)

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that shows the code you are trying to run. It would be best if your example was minimal yet sufficient to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: Have you tried using `.export`?

Comment: @Roland, yep that's it. I found it after a while despite its rather strange description in the manual.