# Searching for row with string value in R data frame

Tags: r, search

i am new to R and i have question regarding searching for data.frame Row.

I have a column
           `msg                 no   tmp     sensor      lat      lon      alt
1 8d4008b858c381ff633cca3d1b59  0 277102796 13020203  0.00000 0.000000     0.00
2 8d4008b858c37575032db3f2f30e  1 136520046 13020203 51.03620 5.892563 11574.78
3 8d40690958af7480e6c539db2d28  2 902340359 13020203  0.00000 0.000000     0.00
4 8d4008b858c37574612e52e5843d  3 185870171 13020203 51.03243 5.904694 11574.78
5 8d4008b858c375764f2c6ea82b0e  4 615986062 13020203 51.04392 5.867767 11574.78
6 8d4008b858c375749f2e15a34831  5 665795000 13020203 51.03387 5.900040 11574.78
7 8d4008b858c37207a9349cd60077  6 576273468 13020203 51.04486 5.864621 11574.78
8 8d40690958af847ff0c66f60ea8e  7 742755281 13020203  0.00000 0.000000     0.00`

the data frame is huge (1.5 million value). I need to check whether there is a row with particular **msg**. ie ,is there a row with ***msg=8d4008b858c37207a9349cd60077***(here row 7)  . If so, return the ***no*** (here return 6) value. Also If there is no such value , it should be notified !

How can i do it efficiently for large data frame???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[msg%chin% '8d4008b858c37207a9349cd60077', no]
#[1] 6
```

Or

```
setDT(df1, key='msg')[.('8d4008b858c37207a9349cd60077'), no]
#[1] 6
```

If we are checking for a value not in the 'msg' column, it will return `NA`

```
setDT(df1, key='msg')[.('xyz'), no]
#[1] NA
```

and to check for `NA` would be to use `is.na`

```
is.na( setDT(df1, key='msg')[.('xyz'), no])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Warlock Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.  According to the example, you have a column named 'msg'.  If we are checking against a value, say 'xyz' not in the 'msg' column, what should be the return value?

Comment: @Warlock Please check my update.  Not sure if that is what you meant

Comment: why 
Error in setDT(sensor1, key = "msg") : unused argument (key = "msg") ?

Comment: @Warlock Can you try with `setkey(setDT(sensor), msg)`?  I am using the devel version of `data.table`.  So, things might be a bit different for your version.  Instructions to install the devel version are [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80476/discussion-between-warlock-and-akrun).

Comment: When i use setDT function in %dopar% , giving an error "could not find function "setDT"...any idea?

Comment: @Warlock I am not sure about the problem.  Is it from `library(parallel)`

Comment: Can you try with `as.data.table(df1)` instead of `setDT`

Comment: you mean change to change table to as.data.table(df1) or ??
as.data.table(df1) what it actually does?

Comment: @Warlock It is because of your error `could not find function `setDT`.  i suggested an equivalent code `as.data.table(sensor)` to convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table`.  I don't have much experience with parallel.  Could you post this as a new question as I am not sure how you got the error?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704235/function-not-found-in-r-doparallel-foreach-error-in-task-1-failed-cou i am using subset function and its working fine